# comparing date drectly using Eloquent when date is stored in a different format in a database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, eloquent

I am writing a program that sends emails to users when their subscription is about to expire so i have a table in my database with a date stored in varchar as `12th April 2018` I am using that format because it is easy to read therefore I don't have to convert it again later.. But when i write

```
$currentdate= Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString();

$threeDaystoExpire =Carbon::now()->addDays(130)->toDateTimeString();

return $expiredPacks = DB::table('subscriptions')
->whereDate('expires_on','>',$currentdate)
->whereDate('expires_on','<=',$threeDaystoExpire)
->get();
```

I get a blank `return` output but when i change `expires_on` to `created_at` that is formatted like this `2018-04-12 12:41:36` I get the correct output. I tried changing the format of `$currentdate` and `$threeDaystoExpire`to match the data in my database as advised by previous threads i read and tried again like this

```
$currentdate= Date('dS F Y', strtotime(Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString()));

$threeDaystoExpire =Date('dS F Y', strtotime(Carbon::now()->addDays(130)->toDateTimeString()));

return $expiredPacks = DB::table('subscriptions')
    ->whereDate('expires_on','>',$currentdate)
    ->whereDate('expires_on','<=',$threeDaystoExpire)
    ->get();
```

I get the same empty output. I am currently stuck. All the posts I've read only uses one value so they just make a statement to return just the date, convert it to a timestamp format then compare. I have hundreds of those date and I cant write a statement for each one so any help to tackle this problem will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a separate field to store the date in a human readable format so I don't have to convert it later in my app, then stored the timestamp format of the same date in a separate field to handle the calculations. It is way easier to use, read and saves me the stress of converting from timestamp then later reconverting back to timestamp which doesn't make sense.

As advised here to leverage platform tools more. I decided that data that will be used in different forms will be stored in a general format and i will allow the platform handle how they want to represent those data.

Answer (score 1):

The `toDateTimeString()` method converts the Carbon DateTime object into a specific format such as `1975-12-25 14:15:16` which simply isn't a match for your varchar field.

Try using the Carbon API to convert Now to the format you need...

```
$currentdate = Carbon::now()->format('dS F Y');
$threeDaystoExpire = Carbon::now()->addDays(130)->format('dS F Y');
```

I'll also point out that the comparison will look at the day first, then the string value of the month, then the numerical year. This will give you *very* odd results. I might recommend `strtotime` on the output of your varchar field and use that instead instead of the other way around.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've thought about that issue too in comparing value of day and then string value of the month, then Numeric value of year and thought about using a loop to convert the dates to a timestamp but I decided to just make a separate table in my database that holds the same date in a different format that makes it easier to compare. I thought about using a loop to change it but I wasn't sure how much memory it would use so I decided to use this method. But I really would love to know more ways to fix this issue

Comment: I take it the issue is making the field human-readable? Store it as a datetime field, and make sure you're converting it to a human-readable format when viewing the data. The value of leveraging the platforms you use cannot be stressed enough; there are plenty of database management tools that allow you to view the field any way you like. Using a second field to keep it readable runs into the problem of field disparity; you're running the risk of relying on one field when the data is in fact something else. Not a problem in a small code snippet, but a major challenge in a large project.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That was exactly what I did I made a separate field to store the date in a human readable format then store the timestamp in a separate field to handle any calculations in regards to the notification

Answer (score 0):

Do yourself a favor and store dates as `YYYY-MM-DD` (in a `date` column), it will make your life much easier. It's also easy to read and has been the standard format for ages (for good reasons).

The format you choose for your frontend is a different matter. You can maybe use an [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) for that.